# Initialise arrays and dictionaries with large numbers of values

Tags: objective-c, c

I need to be able to intialise arrays in my source code with some pre-defined values, that look a bit like below. However each array is going to have possibly thousands of values.

```
@"key",@"value",
@"key",@"value",
@"key",@"value",
@"key",@"value",
...etc...
```

How do I initialse (for example) an `NSDictionary` with these values without having to have thousands of values inline with my source code, ie something like this:

```
tokens = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    #import "keyvaluepairs1.h"
    #import "keyvaluepairs2.h"
    , nil];
```

or even just a pure array like this:

```
char[] tokens = {
    #import "schoolnames.h"
    #import "universitynames.h"
    }
```

What I am looking for is not an objective-c "trick", but more of an understanding on how you can instruct the compiler import or suck in contents of other files. I am open to other ideas on how to achieve this if required.

Comment: Please don't abuse the preprocessor like that...

Comment: How do I avoid having to copy and paste 10,000 values into my source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I believe I have found a simple way to achieve this without having to make sure there are text files lying around everywhere. You can make your header files look like this:

```
#define  SAMPLE_ARRAY \
@"a",   @"value",\
@"b",   @"value",\
@"c",   @"value",\
...etc...
```

And then import or use them like this:

```
tokens = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    SAMPLE_ARRAY
    SAMPLE_ARRAY2
    nil];
```

Given that the data will never change, I can't see any major problems with this.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a plist that is a NSDictionary of NSArrays.  Then easily read the plist into a NSDictionary and then retrieve each array from it.

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFile" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
 NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"array1"];
```

As pointed out, this would be required to be read at least once each time the app is loaded from the 'not running' state

Comment: That is certainly a neat objective c way to do it, I like it. People should consider this option more often. Especially because it means you dont have to write parser code.

Comment: The plist can be very convenient, and easy to parse.  I find that a plist's data structure can be treated similar to JSONs, allowing you to define your own groupings of arrays, dictionarys, strings, and numbers.  This allows it to be very versatile.

Answer (score 0):

If your text file is in the format you show above, you'll need to write a simple parser to read the data into an `NSDictionary`.

Since the format "vocabulary" is simple, a linear parser based on `NSScanner` would be straightforward to implement.

Comment: This would mean you would need to parse the text files each time the application/binary is executed.